# Mysql query to find a value in a range of cumulative sum

Tags: mysql, logic

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 10 |

I want to run select * query ,by using a new column called cumulative_sum , such that this new column is not create to the table rather is being queried (calculated) every time and use to select rows lying between limit and offset, + 1 more row after it.

Suppose I provide offset =130 and limit= 25 (i.e. range 130 to 155) then it should return row 2 row3 and row 4 (ie. last row + 1)

| id | count | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 | 150 |
| 3 | 10 | 160 |
| 4 | 10 | 170 |

How to write a Mysql query for the above condition?

I trying to achieve this for quite some time now please help me to understand  how to do this?

Cummulative sum column is just sum of = last rows cummulative sum + count of present row

Comment: The recent edit you made is confusing, but more importantly it completely invalidates the two answers given below hours earlier.  Please avoid making dramatic edits to your question after other users have already answered.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , The table under output was to generalise cummulative sum calculation and the actual result I wrote in text form("Suppose I provide offset = 130 and limit = 25 (i.e. range 130 to 155) then it should return row 2 row3 and row 4 (ie. last row+1)") above table. Probably that made the confusion so, to clear confusion made the edits.

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 8+, we can simply use `SUM()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id, count, SUM(count) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cumulative_sum
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can use a correlated subquery to find the rolling sum:

```sql
SELECT id, count,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.count) FROM yourTable t2
        WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) AS cumulative_sum
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: this solution doesnot give correct output,
please check the example I have added in the question.

I am looking to get  rows = select rows lying between limit and offset, + 1 more row after it.
limit and offset will be given by user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window function` to achieve this (works with `MySQL 8.0` and above):

```
SELECT id, count, sum(count) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as cummulative_sum
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: this solution does not give correct output,
please check the example I have added in the question.

I am looking to get  rows = select rows lying between limit and offset, + 1 more row after it.
limit and offset will be given by user.